# Sql to Hql query in grails for a very large assosiation

Tags: sql, grails, hql

In my app there's a following relation: Page hasMany Paragraphs and I need to create a query that returns all pages where the number of paragraphs is less then limit. The problem is that the *pages are created in another app approximately 2 per second* and the paragraphs table contains more then **2 million rows**. All standard grails approaches, like dynamic finders and criteria queries just hang as they create very not optimal sql. In the database console the following query does the job:

> `select * from (
>   select a.id, count(b.page_id) count from page a 
>   left join paragraph b ON a.id = b.page_id
>   group by 1) sub
>   WHERE sub.count <= 10 LIMIT 1000`

And I couln't translate this query into HQL. I know there's groovy sql available, but it's rows method returns a List of GroovyResult, not list of domain classes. Is there a better approach to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If a query gets too complicated I tend to do something like this:

```
def results = new Sql(dataSource).rows(SQL)*.id*.asType(Integer).colect(DomainClass.&get)
```

I know it doesn't look too great and you'd probable get no kudos for it but it gets the job done. 
However it if you'd like to use something more expressive you could give a try to JOOQ (http://www.jooq.org/)

Comment: Then you have think about whether you need all the results at one time, whether you can throttle the processing and so on. Loading tens of thousands of results in one go is slow no matter what. To give you an idea - you could use forward cursors akin to JdbcCursorItemReader from Spring Batch, or paginate through the resultset similar to JdbcPagingItemReader.